# Determine which of the following series is convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Determine which of the following series is  convergent.

(a) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+2}}$
(b) $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{a_n}}{n}$ where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n}$ is a convergent series of positive terms

---

How Can I able to prove these ?

which result or test will help me?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

For the first series notice that its general term  isn't convergent to $0$ hence it's a divergent series.

Prove that the  second series is convergent using this inequality:
$$ab\le\frac 12 (a^2+b^2)$$

Comment: But for the first series it is not a series of positive term.How Can I able to use that result

Answer (score 0):

The first series
can be said to converge to a finite set of values.

Let $s_m
=\sum_{n=1}^{m}{(-1)^n\frac{n}{n+2}}
$.
Then

$\begin{align}
s_m
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}(-1)^n(1-\frac{2}{n+2})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}(-1)^n-\sum_{n=1}^{m}{(-1)^n\frac{2}{n+2}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{m}(-1)^n-2\sum_{n=3}^{m}{\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}\\
\end{align}
$

The first sum is $-1$ for odd $m$
and $0$ for even $m$.

The second sum is
(off the top of my head)
$1-2\ln 2$
so the series "converges" to
$1-2\ln 2$
*and*
$-2\ln 2$.